# How to add phtml file content after the form content in backend

Tags: magento2, admin, forms

I have added form in the backend. At the end of the form I need to include a phtml content using it's block. How can we include phtml file after the form content?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code at the end of your phtml form

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Path\to\Block")->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::your_template.phtml")->toHtml()
```

Comment: It comes in the top of the contents...not coming inside the form tab

Comment: Please post your corresponding layout xml

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function to your block

```
public function getFormHtml()
{
    $html = parent::getFormHtml();  
    $html .= $this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::your_template.phtml')->toHtml(); 
    return $html;
}
```

Don't forget to create the phmtl at Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/your_template.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Add in the layout page for customer_index_edit.xml (add in xml file for edit)

`<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="tab/view.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo" name="personal_info" template="tab/view/personal_info.phtml"/>
</block> 
<referenceContainer>`

In tab/view.phtml you call function `echo $block->getChildHtml();`